# bind and trigger function on jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(".box").bind("update",function(txt){
   alert(txt);
}); 


$(".box").trigger("update","Test text");
</script>


<div class="box" style="width:100px;">Nothing to say</div>
```

I want: alert "Test text".

I get: alert "[object Object]"

What is wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/d5rdz71t/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First parameter of the [event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/) is the event object, so accept the data as the second parameter

```js
$(".box").bind("update", function(event, txt) {
  alert(txt);
});

$(".box").trigger("update", "Test text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="width:100px;">Nothing to say</div>
```